# How far in advance can a vegetable filo strudel be made and kept in fridge?

Tags: storage-method, vegetables

I would like to make a roasted vegetable filo pastry strudel 2 days in advance of cooking, is this OK or should it be made the day before?

Comment: What kind of vegetables?  In general, the less moisture in the vegetables, the farther in advance you can assemble it.  This isn't a food safety thing, it's a quality thing -- a lot of moisture transferred from vegetables to dough will ruin the puffing-up effect when it's baked.

Comment: I'd cook them and freeze them; and when serving, just reheat them.

Answer (score 1):

From a food safety perspective, 2 days should be totally fine. Especially since it doesn't sound like you're using animal products.

From a quality perspective, the strudel's freshness might depend on whether you used fresh vs. frozen vegetables and filo (phyllo) dough.